# msvc 2010 application 0xc000007b error

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, qt, dll

I have a project (Qt 4.8.4 based), that uses some external DLL's and two machines:

1) Windows 8 x64

2) Windows 7 x64

I'm developing on first. There is an application, and it debugs perfectly. But when I build it on the 2nd machine, I get the `0cx000007b` error at runtime. The configuration on both machines is exactly the same (except for OS, of course).

The compiler is `MSVC 2010 x86` on both machines. Of course, the x86 external DLL's were built. I see that the OS loads x64 DLL's at runtime. But if it's the problem, how to solve it and why everything is fine on Windows 8?

I've already rebuilt all external libraries on 2nd machine - it doesn't help.

Dependency walker detects some missing DLL's on both machines - it isn't a problem.

MSVC debug crashes after loading of the last external DLL.

How can I finally find the problem?

Comment: Are you mixing 32-bit and 64-bit .dlls?

Answer (score 0):

This was the dumbest thing ever.

The first machine takes openssl dlls from some wifi software, the second - from TortoiseHg (there are x64 dll's).